# why Error: onDateChange is not a function?

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I have this error in my Storybook component, I asked our good friend ChatGPT but he don't help so much. The exact error is this:

> Error: onDateChange is not a function
> at commitHookEffectListMount (/node_modules/.cache/.vite-storybook/deps/chunk-6ZDUWZXD.js?v=fa928d08:16904:34))
> at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (/node_modules/.cache/.vite-storybook/deps/chunk-6ZDUWZXD.js?v=fa928d08:18152:19))
> at commitPassiveMountEffects_complete (/node_modules/.cache/.vite-storybook/deps/chunk-6ZDUWZXD.js?v=fa928d08:18125:17))
> at commitPassiveMountEffects_begin (/node_modules/.cache/.vite-storybook/deps/chunk-6ZDUWZXD.js?v=fa928d08:18115:15))
> at commitPassiveMountEffects (/node_modules/.cache/.vite-storybook/deps/chunk-6ZDUWZXD.js?v=fa928d08:18105:11))
> at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (/node_modules/.cache/.vite-storybook/deps/chunk-6ZDUWZXD.js?v=fa928d08:19486:11))
> at flushPassiveEffects (/node_modules/.cache/.vite-storybook/deps/chunk-6ZDUWZXD.js?v=fa928d08:19443:22))
> at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (/node_modules/.cache/.vite-storybook/deps/chunk-6ZDUWZXD.js?v=fa928d08:18663:40))
> at workLoop (/node_modules/.cache/.vite-storybook/deps/chunk-6ZDUWZXD.js?v=fa928d08:197:42))
> Finally I decided to ask you.

Here is my code (There are some comments in Spanish sorry):

Datepicker.jsx:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import '../App.css';

export default function DatePick({ date, onDateChange }) {
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(''); //Estados de la fecha actual, para poder moverse entre fechas sin problemas.

  const handleDateChange = (e) => { //Se encarga de cambiar la fecha en las constantes necesarias.
    const dateValue = e.target.value;
    setSelectedDate(dateValue);
    onDateChange(dateValue);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!date) { //Si no hay nada en date cargará la fecha actual.
      const currentDate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
      setSelectedDate(currentDate);
      onDateChange(currentDate);
    } else { //Si ya hay (que sería la fecha actual) se pondrá la fecha que tu le pongas.
      setSelectedDate(date);
    }
  }, [date, onDateChange]);

  return ( //Crea el input de tipo date con los valores de mas arriba.
    <div className={`datepicker-state ${selectedDate}`}>
      <div className="datepicker-main">
        <p>Selecciona una fecha:</p>
        <input type="date" name="datepicker" value={selectedDate} onChange={handleDateChange}/>
      </div> 
      {selectedDate !== 'DATE_EMPTY' && <p>Fecha seleccionada: {selectedDate}</p>}
    </div> //Si selectedDate NO es DATE_EMPTY muestra "Fecha seleccionada: (y aquí la fecha elegida por el usuario)".
  );
}
```

Slot.jsx:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { FaUser } from 'react-icons/fa';

export default function Slot({ slot }) {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false); //Estado de cargando para cada Slot.
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(slot.state === 'SLOT_CHECKED'); //Estados para la checkbox.
  const [isHidden, setIsHidden] = useState(false); //Estados para ocultar la checkbox cuando cargue.

  const handleSlotClick = () => { //Si el slot NO está cargando, al hacer click cambiarán los siguientes valores. 
    if (!isLoading) {
      setIsLoading(true); //Estado de carga.
      setIsChecked(prevState => !prevState); //Estado de la checkbox.
      setIsHidden(true); //Estado de visibilidad del slot principal.
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoading) {
      const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        setIsLoading(false);
        setIsHidden(false);
      }, 500); // Duración de carga temporal en milisegundos

      return () => {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
      };
    }
  }, [isLoading]);

  return (
    <div className={`slot ${isChecked ? 'SLOT_CHECKED' : slot.state}`}>
      <div className={`slot-content ${isHidden ? 'hidden' : ''}`} onClick={handleSlotClick}>
        <div className="top-section">
          <label htmlFor="title" aria-label={slot.startTime} className="time">
            <input type="text" value={slot.startTime} readOnly={true} name="title" />
          </label>
          <input type="checkbox" disabled={false} checked={isChecked} className="checkbutton" />
        </div>
        <div className="bottom-section">
          <div className="icon"><FaUser /></div>
          <div className="person">{17 - slot.usersAvailable}/17</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {isLoading && (
        <div className="slot-loading">
          <div className="spinner"></div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

SlotList.jsx:

```
import Slot from './Slot';

export default function SlotList({slots, loading, empty}) {

  const LoadingRow = (
    <div className="slot-loading">
      <div className="spinner"></div>
    </div>
  );

  if(loading) {
    return (
      <div className='list-items' data-testid="loading" key={"loading"}>
        {LoadingRow}
      </div>
    )
  }


  return (
    <div className='list-items'>
      {slots.map((slot, index) => (
        <Slot key={index} slot={slot}/> //Mapea cada uno de los slots por su indice en la API y cada slot en si.
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

ApiGet.jsx(without the key):

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import SlotList from './SlotList';

const ApiGet = ({ date }) => {
  const [slots, setSlots] = useState([]); //Estados de slots para cargarlos en una constante.
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true); //Estados de cargando para el intervalo en el que se hace la petición GET.

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!date) return; // Evita hacer la petición si no hay fecha seleccionada.

    setIsLoading(true); //Lo pone cargando antes de hacer la petición a la API.
    
    axios({
      url: `http://test.services.pixeltiming.com:4400/booking/availability?date=${date}`,
      headers: {
        Authorization: '',
      },
    }) //Después de la conexión mapeará cada slot con el startTime reducido a HH:MM si hay algo en el get.
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data?.data?.slots) {
          const formattedSlots = response.data.data.slots.map((slot) => {
            const startTime = slot.startTime.substring(0, 5);
            return { ...slot, startTime };
            /*const formattedSlots = response.data.data.slots.map((slot) => {
                const startTime = slot.startTime.substring(0, 5);
                return {...slot, startTime};*/
          });
          setSlots(formattedSlots); //Se cargan los slots mapeados en la constante slots de mas arriba.
          //setSlots(response.data.data.slots);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => { 
        console.log(error);
      })
      .finally(() => { //Elimina el valor de Cargando al terminar la petición para quitar el texto y poner los slots.
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  }, [date]);

  return ( //Si está "isLoading" pondrá cargando. Si está vacío pondrá que no hay.
    <div className="class1">
      <h3 id="h3-sesiones">Elige una sesión o varias:</h3>
      {isLoading ? (
        <div class="loader"></div>
      ) : slots.length === 0 ? ( 
        <div className='no-slots'>
          <p>¡No hay slots disponibles!</p>
          <p className='emojis-no-slots'></p>
          <p>Prueba en otra fecha.</p>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <SlotList slots={slots} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ApiGet;
```

App.jsx:

```
import './App.css';
import DatePick from './components/Datepicker';
import ApiGet from './components/ApiGet';
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  //Cargar prop de fecha para usarlo en ApiGet y Datepicker con el mismo valor (para la url de la API).
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(null);

  const handleDateChange = (date) => {
    setSelectedDate(date);
  };
//Cargar los componentes necesarios y sus atributos de fecha.
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <DatePick date={selectedDate} onDateChange={handleDateChange} />
      <ApiGet date={selectedDate} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And the storybook files:

Datepicker.stories.jsx:

```
import DatePick from "./Datepicker";

export default {
    component: DatePick,
    title: 'Datepicker',
    tags: ['autodocs'],
};

export const Default = {
    args: {
        datepick: {
            id: '1',
            title: 'testDatepicker',
            state: 'DATE_EMPTY',
            picked: false,
        },
    },
};

export const Picked = {
    args: {
        datepick: {
            ...Default.args.datepick,
            state: 'DATE_PICKED',
            picked: true,
        },
    },
};
```

Slot.stories.jsx:

```
import Slot from "./Slot";

export default {
    component: Slot,
    title: 'Slot',
    tags: ['autodocs'],
};

const Template = (args) => <Slot {...args}/>;
export const Default = Template.bind({});
Default.args = {
    slot: {
        id: '1',
        title: 'Test',
        state: 'SLOT_INBOX',
    },
}

export const Disabled = {
    args: {
        slot: {
            ...Default.args.slot,
            state: 'SLOT_DISABLED',
        },
    },
};

export const Checked = {
    args: {
        slot: {
            ...Default.args.slot,
            state: 'SLOT_CHECKED',
        },
    },
};
```

SlotList.stories.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import * as SlotStories from './Slot.stories';
import SlotList from './SlotList';

export default {
  component: SlotList,
  title: 'SlotList',
  decorators: [story => <div style={{ padding: '3rem' }}>{story()}</div>],
};

const Template = args => <SlotList {...args} />;

export const Default = Template.bind({});
Default.args = {
  // Shaping the stories through args composition.
  // The data was inherited from the Default story in Task.stories.js.
  slots: [
    { ...SlotStories.Default.args.slot, id: '1', title: '16:00' },
    { ...SlotStories.Default.args.slot, id: '2', title: '16:15' },
    { ...SlotStories.Default.args.slot, id: '3', title: '16:30' },
    { ...SlotStories.Default.args.slot, id: '4', title: '16:45' },
    { ...SlotStories.Default.args.slot, id: '5', title: '17:00' },
    { ...SlotStories.Default.args.slot, id: '6', title: '17:15' },
  ],
};

export const Loading = Template.bind({});
Loading.args = {
  slots: [],
  loading: true,
};

export const CheckedAndNot = Template.bind({});
CheckedAndNot.args = {
    slots: [
        { ...SlotStories.Default.args.slot, id: '1', title: '16:00', state: 'SLOT_CHECKED'},
        { ...SlotStories.Default.args.slot, id: '2', title: '16:15', state: 'SLOT_CHECKED'},
        ...Default.args.slots.slice(2, 6),
    ],
}
```

Sorry for the lots of text and thanks for helping.

I tried putting onDateChange like a prop in the API class.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

This type of error often occurs when you attempt to call a function on somthing that is undefined.

Also, commitHookEffectListMount does not appear in the code you shared, I imagine it is in some other component. What you could do is track it's value to see if at some point it becomes undefined (or something you can't call your function on).